# What is the minimum voltage to shock someone? Is a transformer needed or can I use a battery?

Tags: batteries, transformer, shock

What is the minimum voltage to shock someone (on the arm, leg, or finger, not on the tongue). Could this be achieved with just a battery and without a transformer? Is shocking someone just a matter of how close you put the two poles together? I have found that a nine volt battery applied directly to the skin has no shock of any kind.

Comment: Did you try licking the contacts of the 9V battery?

Comment: Yes, my tongue got shocked but I am looking to shock my arm or leg with a battery.

Comment: You can kill someone in everyday life with a 36V low impedance supply. It's happened (helicopter battery). If you keep current under a few mA you won't kill most people most times. YMMV :-( . 75 VAC telepohne ringers at about 17 Hertz can be very exciting. | A reasonable approach is an inductive spike at low duty cycle and lowish frequency and low net energy..These will not usually kill people. Someone with heart issues or bad luck may help you break the norm. How many people did you hope to kill?

Comment: Welders died than performing welding process I tight spaces, like big pipe. And it is only 36-40V. So the timing of electricity affecting is important sometimes.

Comment: Telephone distribution panels use 50 volts dc with a ringer AC voltage on top of that. In summer, if I lean my bare forearm bottomside against the terminals, I feel a strong tingle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe around 60-70 V in dry conditions.

I work with 60 VDC a lot. I am careful but I have never been shocked by it. I suspect it won't normally shock you with light contact.

I believe that from a safety perspective, 48 V is often regarded as the highest safe voltage for dry condtions.

And maybe 12 V for very damp conditions (outside in the rain).

I was once very mildly shocked by 50 or 55 VDC, but it was hot and I had been perspiring and was leaning against a large metal structure that was grounded. It was just a light tingle.

Shocking people is not particularly safe and is probably best avoided. Some people have pacemakers, and it seems to me that perhaps a pacemaker could be damaged if you shock someone. Also, since the susceptibility of people varies, and humidity and other factors vary, there could be some danger that you overdo it accidentally.

Comment: Wouldn't I have to watch the current by adding resistors or something along those lines?

Comment: @LDM31 you should take some steps to make absolutely sure that the current is limited, yes.  I have seen varying reports, but I think 1mA might give you a mild shock but would be unlikely to do any harm to a healthy person. And as little as 5 mA can give a painful shock. It is also worse if the current passes through your chest since it may disrupt your heart. So avoid having current pass from one hand to the other as it may go right through your chest. This has been discussed on this site quite a few times. You should search for shock related questions.

Comment: ok, thanks. I think I will just discard this idea but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

You can kill someone in everyday life with a 36V low impedance supply. It's happened (helicopter battery).

If you keep current under a few mA you won't kill most people most times. YMMV :-( .

75 VAC telepohne ringers at about 17 Hertz can be very exciting.

A reasonable approach is an inductive spike at low duty cycle and lowish frequency and low net energy..These will not usually kill people. Someone with heart issues or bad luck may help you break the norm. How many people did you hope to kill?

Answer (score 2):

This is one of those ethical conundrums that show up here every so often. I don’t think it’s a good idea to make such a thing.

Safety standards consider voltages below 60VDC / 42.4VAC to be 'touch safe', as in unlikely to deliver a harmful shock. Leakage current is limited to less than 3.5mA RMS.

IEC 60479-1 sets out parameters for shock reactions:

- perception: 0.5mA AC RMS
- involuntary contractions, no harmful effects
- strong involuntary contractions, difficulty breathing, possible immobilization
- burns, cardiac/respiratory arrest, ventricular fibrillation

The thresholds are complex, given as curves in IEC 60479-1 for the higher thresholds. If you're serious about this, you'd be well advised to consult this doc.

That said, the cheap ‘shock gag’ toys tend to use some kind of a coil to step up the voltage enough to feel a shock. Well-designed ones have some measures to limit the energy they deliver, like series resistance for example.

This video does some analysis and tear down of cheap shock toys. https://youtu.be/WTH2LVuDe6g

Comment: When I was young (5 or 6 years old) one of the older kids was offering to show others his "Moon Machine." He said "here, hold these 2 rods and I will crank the machine so you can see the moon." He didn't fool me, and I went on to become an electronics technician.

Answer (score 0):

You need higher voltage to make shock on skin (leg or sth) because of higher resistance (changes with humidity). Transformer (or simply step up converter) is probabbly best option to step up voltage, but there are also charge pumps without transformator.